# Do I need to restart Apache after changing the php.ini file?

Tags: php, apache

If I make a change to a setting in the php.ini file - do I need to restart Apache in order for it to take effect?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Depends, actually. Depends on how you use php inside that webserver:

- using php as module inside the http server: you have to restart the http server process
- using php as cgi backend: you do *not* have to restart the http server process or anything else
- using php fastcgi: you have to restart the fastcgi daemon, not the http server
- using php-fpm: you have to restart the fpm server process, not the http server process

Comment: PHP-FPM you need to restart to avoid configuration inconsistency. Some workers will lay dormant and keep the old configuration, while new workers will get the new configuration.

Comment: Maybe I should be asking a new question, but how do I _know_ how PHP is used?

Comment: @osullic Certainly go and as your question, that is what this site is for, isn't it? ;-) But _before_ asking... what do you actually mean by "PHP is used"? Sounds trivial at first, but is it? How would you say that assertion is true for a given http server, when?

Comment: How would someone, who has inherited a php/apache project, go about determining this set up?

Comment: @scrollout Depends on your setup, actually. Let's have a chat: 
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244443/do-i-need-to-restart-apache-after-changing-the-php-ini-file

Comment: Followup question: is a `graceful` restart sufficient in cases where a restart is needed?

Comment: @twhitney Yes, that is just fine.

Answer (score 18):

On Debian 8 I had to restart PHP-FPM (and Apache)
The above answers are correct, but here are the commands so you won't have to googling them.

Restart Apache :

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Restart php5-fpm :

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: This actually depends on the distribution you are using, the required commands differ.

Comment: I found [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/189961/243621) that shows php-fpm restart based on the PHP version you are running.

Answer (score 7):

That depends on the SAPI you're using. If you're using PHP as an Apache module for example, you need to restart apache so that the `php.ini` values take effect.

If you're using FCGI, you need to restart the FCGI daemon for the PHP script that you want to see the values changed. Compare with

- [Trouble changing `upload_max_filesize` on nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8028692/367456)

Comment: just to be sure, by SAPI you mean Server API?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what OS and version you are running.

I am running Apache/2.4.29 under Ubuntu.

PHP Version 7.2.24.

I restart apache with the following command and the restart is needed after modifying the php.ini file:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about Apache but on Windows with IIS a restart is not required.

Either way, considering the myriad of different configurations out there with PHP, an easy way to check is to load your phpinfo.php file in a browser and confirm the value of a setting, then change that setting in php.ini and reload phpinfo.php to see if it's picking up your change.

If you don't know what I mean by "phpinfo.php" check this page:  https://blogtimenow.com/knowledge-base/create-phpinfo-php-file-page/

Comment: although its not helpful with apache, saying that it is not needed in iis is ONLY correct if the ini-file is monitored by iis