# Error enableing OAuth Drupal 7 module

Tags: curl, oauth, drupal-7, wampserver

I am trying to enable OAuth Drupal 7 module however I am getting this error:

DrupalOAuthClient requires the PHP cURL library. (Currently using OAuth cURL library not found)

I have WAMP server php_curl extension is checked and extension=php_curl.dll in both php.ini is not commented. In the same time phpinfo() does not show CURL

What could be the problem?

Comment: Anyone knows a solution for this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your WAMP server to load the configuration?

Apache often needs a restart when you change a setting for PHP.
[Do I need to restart Apache after changing the php.ini file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892331/do-i-need-to-restart-apache-after-changing-the-php-ini-file)