# how to change OPCache configuration

Tags: php, centos, opcache, directadmin

I put my custom configuration in php.ini file but configuration doesn't change.

```
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
opcache.validate_timestamps=0 
opcache.max_accelerated_files=7963
opcache.memory_consumption=256
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=16
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

i use centos and directadmin and installed opcache by custombuild
is there another way to change default configs?

Comment: have you bounced Apache (or whatever webserver you're using?)

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean!?

Comment: See [Do I need to restart Apache after changing the php.ini file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892331/do-i-need-to-restart-apache-after-changing-the-php-ini-file)

Comment: i restarted the Apache several times
opcache.enable=1 and opcache.enable=0

Comment: opcache.enable=1 and opcache.enable=0 works fine but the rest of configs doesn't work

Comment: what do you by 'doesn't work'? are you using phpinfo() to confirm your opcache settings, after restarting Apache?

Comment: yes, i using phpinfo() and there is no change

Answer (score 1):

i find the solution ,
some of configs was predefined  in /usr/local/lib/php.conf.d/10-directadmin.ini
i deleted the predefined  configurations and change the configs in php.ini file then that works fine.