# How to secure session through php.ini file

Tags: php, apache, session, session-cookies, ini

In my root directory i have php.ini file & it have some lines like this

```
session.save_path = "/tmp"
session.use_cookies = 1
;session.cookie_secure =
; session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_httponly = 
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file =
session.name = PHPSESSID
;session.entropy_length = 16

;session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom
session.use_trans_sid = 0

; Select a hash function
; 0: MD5   (128 bits)
; 1: SHA-1 (160 bits)
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

I have tried editing these above lines for e.g

```
session.name = MYSITE
```

But editing above code doesn't make any changes to my session.
Is there an another way or i'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Ensure that you are editing the correct php.ini file, use `phpinfo()` to see what config file(s) is/are loaded

Comment: I have checked it already, it's loading the correct file

Comment: Should work then, you may need to restart the server after editing ini file (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892331/do-i-need-to-restart-apache-after-changing-the-php-ini-file)