# Laravel - SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

Whenever I try to run any php artisan commands on my laravel installation on local machine, it gives

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

The same codebase works fine on other machines. My local machine runs on wamp with Windows 10 installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [a solution](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/replies/37017) I've used when I was using a Windows laptop.

Download [the certificate](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem).

Add or edit this line in `php.ini` config:

```
curl.cainfo = "[path_to_cerfificate]\cacert.pem"
```

And then restart your computer.

Comment: do we require a full system restart or restarting the server will do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892331/do-i-need-to-restart-apache-after-changing-the-php-ini-file

Comment: I have accepted the answer because the problem lied with firewall settings which blocked the external certificate validations