# Why do I need to restart my computer after changing date.timezone in my php.ini file?

Tags: php, apache, server

**CHALLENGE**

I changed the `date.timezone` in the `php.ini` file, and when I entered `php-i` in my terminal, it showed me the correct `date.timezone`, however the new `date.timezone` wasn't reflecting in my `<?phpinfo()` page on localhost.

**THINGS I TRIED**

I know that when a change is made to the `php.ini` file, the server has to be restarted. I am using the built in Apache server on MacOS, and the commands I have used so far are

- sudo apachectl restart
- sudo apachectl graceful
- apachectl -k restart

All these failed to reflect the new `date.timezone` in my `phpinfo()` localhost page, when I refreshed the page.

**HOW I SOLVED THE CHALLENGE**

I had a similar issue in the past with this same configuration, when I changed the default php version on my laptop. The terminal command `php -v` showed the new version, but the `<?phpinfo()` page wasn't reflecting the new version, even after using the Apache restart commands stated above and refreshing the page. On a whim, I decided to restart my laptop and the `<?phpInfo()` localhost page reflected the new php version.

I decided to restart my computer after many painful attempts at restarting my Apache server and refreshing the `<?phpinfo()`localhost page didn't reflect the new `date.timezone` - it worked.

**QUESTION**

Why do I need to restart my computer for changes to be reflected in the `<?phpinfo()`localhost page? It doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: If PHP is running in [FPM mode](https://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm), or similar, you might need to reload that process instead.

Comment: How do I know what mode it is running in, @ChrisHaas? Also, I used `brew services restart php@7.4` and it still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892331/do-i-need-to-restart-apache-after-changing-the-php-ini-file

Comment: @Tony, unfortunately I don't have a Mac available right now for testing, but hopefully Melvin's post gets you there. On Linux, we'd do something like `sudo service php7.4-fpm reload`.

Comment: Also, the reason that your CLI is always up to date is that the CLI re-loads the .ini (and .conf files) each time it is run. The FPM process does the same, however it is continuously running so you need to stop and start it.

Comment: Thanks, @Melvin and Chris for your help.